# Why answer is coming as 2:2:1:1 when we are removing all elements of a SET

Tags: java, collections, set

When we will add elements in a Set,it will discard the duplicate values.When we are removing the elements of set k1 and k2. Still final size is 1. Answer of code is 2:2:1:1.

```
class KeyMaster {
    public int i;

    public KeyMaster(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return i == ((KeyMaster) o).i;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }
}


public class MapIt  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<KeyMaster> set = new HashSet<KeyMaster>();
        KeyMaster k1 = new KeyMaster(1);
        KeyMaster k2 = new KeyMaster(2);
        set.add(k1);
        set.add(k1);
        set.add(k2);
        set.add(k2);

        System.out.print(set.size() + ":");
        k2.i = 1;

        System.out.print(set.size() + ":");
        set.remove(k1);

        System.out.print(set.size() + ":");
        set.remove(k2);

        System.out.print(set.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: set.remove(k2) return false that’s why it remains size 1.

Comment: @ParaSara sourav problem is why this return false. OP expect it to work fine

Answer (score 1):

This is because **Key in HashSet is not immutable** so when you change a field value of `k2`, this field value changed but the object remain the same, so when you want to remove `k2` from the set, it cant find k2 because your object have been changed.

for understanding it better let `k1` go and test this:

```
class MapIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<KeyMaster> set = new HashSet<KeyMaster>();
        KeyMaster k2 = new KeyMaster(2);
        set.add(k2);
        set.add(k2);

        System.out.print(set.size() + ":");
        k2.i = 3;
        System.out.print(set.size() + ":");
        set.remove(k2);

        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map` (interface of `HashMap` that is behind-the-scene of `HashSet`s) API say:

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map
>   keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object
>   is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the
>   object is a key in the map.

Your `hashCode` is badly defined, it should at least ensure the following (from API):

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.